# When I receive my data, I save it to Core Data and start downloading the images. How do I link downloaded images to their Core Data counterparts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, asynchronous

I call an API which then gives me a bunch of posts from the website. Each post contains a title, description and a thumbnail. I save the title and description and start the download of the image, but I'm confused how I then link up the image once downloaded with the object in Core Data it responded to.

I then have a `UITableView` with a `NSFetchedResultsController` that populates the table view with the Core Data objects.

```
for (WebServicePost *post in NSArray *posts) {
    Post *newPost = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newPost.title = post.title;
    newPost.info = post.info;

    NSURLSessionDataTask *imageDataTask = [self.downloadSession dataTaskWithURL:[post.URL imgurThumbnailURLWithSize:CSImgurThumbnailSizeSmall] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

-->     // What do I do here?
    }];

    [imageDataTask resume];
}

NSError *coreDataError;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&coreDataError]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

I'm confused how I link the downloaded image to a cell in the table view.

My plan was to have an `NSCache` that mapped the `indexPath` of each cell to the corresponding `UIImage`, but at this point I don't know the indexPath of the cell. I can't call `indexPathForObject:` either, as it hasn't been saved to Core Data yet.

I then considered mapping the `Post` object itself to the `UIImage`, instead of the `indexPath`, but this made my fearful as if the `Post` object changes, the one I had a reference to will no longer work, as it's the initial `Post` object.

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I'd check if there was an image, if so I'd use it, if not I'd just continue waiting for it.

I'm confused how to match this up properly though. Is my setup wrong?

Comment: Is your end goal to put the downloaded images into a UITableView in a way that the correct image is with the corresponding data in the cell?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start your for loop, make sure you add this line:

```
NSMutableArray *cellData = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Then in the "What do I do here part" type this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *postData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[postData setObject:post forKey:@"post"];
[postData setObject:downloadedImage forKey:@"image"];
[cellData addObject:[postData copy]];
```

Now you can cycle through your cellData, and every image will be matched up with its post data because they are being pointed to through a dictionary!

So to get a post and it's image you could do this:

```
NSDictionary *data = [postData objectAtIndex:1];
[data objectForKey:@"post"]; //will return your post data for post in index 1
[data objectForKey:@"image"]; //will return your image for post in index 1
```

Comment: Yes, but when I do `setObject:post` it's what `post` is at that moment. If `post` changes between then and when I retrieve it, I won't be able to retrieve it properly as they'll be different objects.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm understanding your dilemma with this. Answer this though; will the post changing change the order of the posts?

Comment: Okay, one more question, will the post changing require you to set the new data to a new allocation of a post variable? Or will the post changing only change the properties in the current post object.